# imake on mingw or on windows

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, imake

I have a fully developed and operational application on `linux`. Now I have been asked that I adapt the application for `windows`.

The simplest way I found is using `mingw`. However, I am confronted with the problem that a part of the application depends on `imake`. Of course, I could start from the `makefiles` generated by  imake  and from there to solve.

But before that, I would ask if there is any wrapper or support (although partial) for `imake` on `windows`  and how it could be adapted to `mingw`